# Search a string on the specific columns using GREP/AWK/CUT

Tags: awk, grep, cut

Kindly modify my script, because I want to search the word "dBm" in Column 1,3, and 4 of File.csv and return all unmatched lines/records 'cause "dBm" need to be deleted on the file.

```
cat File.csv | grep -v dBm | sort -u -t '|' -k 1,1 -k 3,4 > Result.csv

Sample File.csv
RefNum|Date|Info|LTC|ICD|MLBB
ABC123|010119|19 dBm||Milk|MII9
DEF456|010119|21|-5 dBm|Choco|KK20
GHI789|010219|||C2|AA30
JKL111|010219|54|17||SK10

Sample Result.csv
RefNum|Date|Info|LTC|ICD|MLBB
GHI789|010219|||C2|AA30
JKL111|010219|54|17||SK10
```

Badly needed you're help! Cheers.

Comment: why not `egrep -v dBm File.csv > Result.csv`? do the other columns take dBm value as well and should not be removed?

Comment: Yes, other column takes "dBm" but I only need the string should be search only in Column 1,3,and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` to extract the lines that does not contain the string `dBm` as a substring in columns 1, 3, or 4:

```
awk -F '|' '!($1 ~ /dBm/ || $3 ~ /dBm/ || $4 ~ /dBm/)' file
```

Given your first piece of data, this would output

```
RefNum|Date|Info|LTC|ICD|MLBB
GHI789|010219|||C2|AA30
JKL111|010219|54|17||SK10
```

The `awk` program matches `dBm` against each of the three columns, and if there is no match against any of them, it outputs the original line.

Comment: Great! It works fine! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '($1 FS $3 FS $4) !~ /dBm/' file
RefNum|Date|Info|LTC|ICD|MLBB
GHI789|010219|||C2|AA30
JKL111|010219|54|17||SK10
```